# Why does bool variables hold negative value and consider it as TRUE?

Tags: c++

Isn't bool supposed to hold only 1 and 0 only?

```
bool a = -1;
```

gives me `TRUE` value.

Comment: __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C__, They are differnet languages and demand to be treaed as such. :) Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Choose one and stick to that please.

Comment: Also, have you done research by searching for how `bool` is treated in your language of choice?

Comment: Anything different from 0 is considered true.

Comment: Anything non-zero is true.

Comment: Guys I don't see a reason of downvoting. Please describe the reason, or remove the downvote

Comment: The actual representation of booleans is unspecified by the standard. How integers convert to and from booleans is independent of the booleans' representation.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Although it must be true that sizeof(bool) >= sizeof(char)

Comment: @Bathsheba Of course; the size of something can't be zero.

Comment: Does bool take 1 byte of memory?

Comment: @RickSanchez: Absolutely not. That's a common misconception. It has to take as much memory as a `char`. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just because only the value `0` is considered as `FALSE`. All the other values are considered as `TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

Only 0 evaluates to false. Everything else evaluates to true. You might be associating negative with false, but that isn’t the case here with bool.